# Martian Robots - a small JS program

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, underscore.js

Please look at a small piece of code I wrote and provide some thoughts, critiques and any feedback you think is needed.

The code is here along with the problem I have attempted to solve and I look forward to hearing all your thoughts on it.

> **The Problem**
>
> The surface of Mars can be modelled by a rectangular grid around which
>   robots are able to move according to instructions provided from Earth.
>   You are to write a program that determines each sequence of robot
>   positions and reports the final position of the robot.
>
> A robot position consists of a grid coordinate (a pair of integers:
>   x-coordinate followed by y-coordinate) and an orientation (N, S, E, W
>   for north, south, east, and west).
>
> A robot instruction is a string of the letters "L", "R", and "F" which
>   represent, respectively, the instructions:
>
> - Left: the robot turns left 90 degrees and remains on the current grid point.
> - Right: the robot turns right 90 degrees and remains on the current grid point.
> - Forward: the robot moves forward one grid point in the direction of the current orientation and maintains the same orientation.
>
> The direction North corresponds to the direction from grid point (x,
>   y) to grid point (x, y+1). There is also a possibility that additional
>   command types maybe required in the future and provision should be
>   made for this. Since the grid is rectangular and bounded (...yes Mars
>   is a strange planet), a robot that moves "off" an edge of the grid is
>   lost forever. However, lost robots leave a robot "scent" that
>   prohibits future robots from dropping off the world at the same grid
>   point. The scent is left at the last grid position the robot occupied
>   before disappearing over the edge. An instruction to move "off" the
>   world from a grid point from which a robot has been previously lost is
>   simply ignored by the current robot.
>
> **The Input**
>
> The first line of input is the upper-right coordinates of the
>   rectangular world, the lower-left coordinates are assumed to be 0, 0.
>
> The remaining input consists of a sequence of robot positions and
>   instructions (two lines per robot). A position consists of two
>   integers specifying the initial coordinates of the robot and an
>   orientation (N, S, E, W), all separated by whitespace on one line. A
>   robot instruction is a string of the letters "L", "R", and "F" on one
>   line.
>
> Each robot is processed sequentially, i.e., finishes executing the
>   robot instructions before the next robot begins execution.
>
> The maximum value for any coordinate is 50.
>
> All instruction strings will be less than 100 characters in length.
>
> **The Output**
>
> For each robot position/instruction in the input, the output should
>   indicate the final grid position and orientation of the robot. If a
>   robot falls off the edge of the grid the word "LOST" should be printed
>   after the position and orientation.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> - 1 1 E RFRFRFRF
> - 3 2 N FRRFLLFFRRFLL
> - 0 3 W LLFFFLFLFL
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> - 1 1 E
> - 33 N LOST
> - 2 3 S

**My Solution**

```
//  robot factory
//  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  the robotFactory is a factory method used for creating new robots to explore Mars.
//  there is a dependency on Underscore for some object extension although this could
//  have been written as a constructor or in the future using the native Object.assign().
//
//  ==  EXAMPLE   =======================================================================
//
//  var robotFactory = require('./src/robot'),
//      dave = robotFacotry({x: 27, y: 12, heading: 'E'});
//
//  dave.instruct('lrlflfrlflrfffrlfl');
//  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;(function (_, undefined) {

  'use strict';

  module.exports = (function () {
    var losses  = [],
        compass = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W'],
        bounds  = {
          min: { x: 0,  y: 0  },
          max: { x: 50, y: 25 }
        };

    return function (options) {
      var defaults = _.extendOwn({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            heading: 'N'
          }, options),

          //  moves
          //  -------------------------------------
          //  a collection of the robot's movements
          //  which could be useful.
          //  -------------------------------------
          moves = [],

          //  is within bounds?
          //  --------------------------------------
          //  check whether a set of coordinates are
          //  within a set boundary.
          //  ======================================
          //  @arg      {object}  coords
          //  @returns  {boolean}
          //  --------------------------------------
          isWithinBounds = function (coords) {
            if (!coords instanceof Object)
              throw new TypeError();

            var lastMove = moves[moves.length - 1],
                move     = _.extend({}, lastMove, coords);

            return ((move.x >= bounds.min.x && move.x <= bounds.max.x) &&
                    (move.y >= bounds.min.y && move.y <= bounds.max.y));
          },

          //  add move
          //  ----------------------------------------------------------------
          //  checks whether the latest coordinates are within the boundaries
          //  or if it the robot has been lost, if it is it'll add a new entry
          //  to the moves collection else it will also add the coordinates to
          //  the losses collection.
          //  ================================================================
          //  @arg      {object}  coords
          //  ----------------------------------------------------------------
          addMove = function (coords) {
            if (!coords instanceof Object)
              throw new TypeError();

            var lastMove = moves[moves.length - 1],
                move     = _.extend({}, lastMove, coords);

            if (lastMove.lost)
              return;

            if (isWithinBounds(move)) {
              moves.push(move);
            } else {
              if (!(_.filter(losses, function (loss) {
                return [loss.x, loss.y].toString() === [move.x, move.y].toString();
              }).length)) {
                moves.push(_.extend({lost: true}, move));
                losses.push(move);
              }
            }
          },

          //  turn
          //  -------------------------------------------
          //  gets the current heading of the robot,
          //  updates the heading and calls addMove to
          //  add a new movement to the moves collection.
          //  ===========================================
          //  @arg      {number}  dir
          //  -------------------------------------------
          turn = function (dir) {
            if (typeof dir !== 'number')
              throw new TypeError();

            var lastMove = moves[moves.length - 1],
                currentHeading = compass.indexOf(lastMove.heading);

            currentHeading = currentHeading + dir;

            if (currentHeading < 0)
              currentHeading = 3;

            else if (currentHeading > 3)
              currentHeading = 0;

            addMove({
              heading: compass[currentHeading]
            });
          },

          //  move
          //  -------------------------------------------------
          //  checks which way to move the robot and then calls
          //  the addMove method to perform the checks and add
          //  to the collection.
          //  -------------------------------------------------
          move = function () {
            var move = {},
                lastMove = moves[moves.length - 1];

            if (lastMove.heading.match(/n/i))
              move.y = lastMove.y + 1;

            else if (lastMove.heading.match(/e/i))
              move.x = lastMove.x + 1;

            else if (lastMove.heading.match(/s/i))
              move.y = lastMove.y - 1;

            else if (lastMove.heading.match(/w/i))
              move.x = lastMove.x - 1;

            addMove(move);
          };

      //  add an initial position when the robot created.
      moves.push({
        x: defaults.x,
        y: defaults.y,
        heading: defaults.heading
      });

      return {
        //  instruct
        //  ------------------------------------------------------
        //  this method allows you to give your robot instructions
        //  on how to move over the surface of Mars.
        //  ======================================================
        //  @arg      {string}  instructions
        //  @returns  {string}  last position
        //  ------------------------------------------------------
        instruct: function (instructions) {
          if (typeof instructions !== 'string')
            throw new TypeError();

          if (instructions.length >= 100)
            throw new Error('Instruction string must be less than 100 characters');

          if (instructions.match(/^[l|r|f]*$/i)) {
            instructions.split('').forEach(function (instruction) {
              if (instruction.match(/l/i))
                turn(-1);

              else if (instruction.match(/r/i))
                turn(1);

              else if (instruction.match(/f/i))
                move();
            });

            var lastMove = moves[moves.length - 1];

            return lastMove.x + ' ' + lastMove.y + ' ' + lastMove.heading +
              ((lastMove.lost) ? ' LOST' : '');
          } else
            throw new Error('Instructions can only include a combination of L, R and F');
        }
      };
    };
  } ());

} (require('underscore')));
```

[Full solution with Jasmine tests](https://github.com/adjohnston/mars-robot/tree/master)

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/ribuhuqaku/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thing on the regular expression of your `instruct` function.

If you pass an empty string, `/^[l|r|f]*$/i` will find a match, but the robot won't do any moves, so it won't return any value, failing the purpose of the robot.

Maybe force instructions with at least one command `/^[l|r|f]+$/i`